# How do you select only the maximum version of a list of documents that have different versions in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a database table that looks like this:

```
| ID | TITLE | VERSION | 
| 1  | file1 |    1    |
| 2  | file2 |    1    |
| 3  | file1 |    2    |
| 4  | file2 |    2    |
```

I need an SQL query that will return rows 3 and 4 because they are the latest versions of file1 and file 2.

If I run the query on a table that looks like this:

```
| ID | TITLE | VERSION | 
| 1  | file1 |    1    |
| 2  | file2 |    1    |
| 3  | file1 |    2    |
| 4  | file2 |    2    |
| 5  | file3 |    1    |
```

It should return rows 3,4 and 5 because "file3" version1 is the latest version of file3.

I know I need to use "MAX" function in SQL, however I'm getting throw off with the "GROUP BY" keyword.  I'm not very familiar with how to use it.

Would appreciate all / any advice!

We are using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, use a subquery to obtain the `MAX` version, grouped by  `TITLE`, and then join the result of it with your table to obtain the `ID`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl t INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT title, MAX(version) version
      FROM tbl
      GROUP BY title
     ) max_t ON (t.version = max_t.version AND t.title = max_t.title);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58558/2)**.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best way to do this is using the ranking functions:

```
select id, title, version
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

The function row_number() is called an analytic function in Oracle.  It assigns number 1, 2, 3 . . . to each row, based on the partitioning clause.  The numbers start over at each id, and the largest version starts at 1.