# How to select the maximum version of a document from a list of document in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you select only the maximum version of a list of documents that have different versions in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397330/how-do-you-select-only-the-maximum-version-of-a-list-of-documents-that-have-diff)

I have a table of that stores versions of files and the page those files are associated with

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, title varchar(32), version int, pageid int);
insert into tbl values (1, 'file1', 1, 25);
insert into tbl values (2, 'file2', 1, 25);
insert into tbl values (3, 'file1', 2, 25);
insert into tbl values (4, 'file2', 2, 25);
insert into tbl values (5, 'file3', 1, 25);
insert into tbl values (6, 'file1', 1, 24);
insert into tbl values (7, 'file2', 1, 24);
insert into tbl values (8, 'file1', 2, 24);
insert into tbl values (9, 'file2', 2, 24);
insert into tbl values (10, 'file3', 1, 24);
```

I would like to generate a query that returns to me only the maximum versions of documents that are attached to pageid=25, not pageid=24.  Running the query should yield only rows 3,4,5 and not rows 8,9,10 (because they are associated with pageid=24).

I have put together a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33a3b/3) for this problem.

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, but similar.  I forgot to mention more details that complicated the query in the previous post, but those who answered the previous post correctly got points anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple query which does the trick:

```
select *
from tbl t1
inner join (select title, max(version) as version from tbl where pageid=25 group by 1) t2 on(t1.title=t2.title and t1.version=t2.version)
where t1.pageid=25
```

And here's its [SQL Fiddle output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33a3b/38) -- does it do what you're looking for?

Comment: This one worked perfectly on Oracle 11g.

Comment: Cool--I figured I'd use standard SQL for maximum portability.  Happy to hear it works.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the tags on the question are correct (the fiddle you posted is for MySQL), you can use analytic functions

```
SELECT id, title, version, pageid
  FROM (SELECT t.*, 
               MAX(version) OVER (partition by title) max_version
          FROM tbl t
         where pageid=25)
 WHERE version = max_version;
```

You can see the [SQL Fiddle for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33a3b/1/0) returns the three rows in question

Comment: Your query works on the SQL Fiddle site but when I entered it on our Oracle 11g database it did not work.

Comment: @user1068636 - Can you elaborate on "did not work"?  It works on SQL Fiddle (which is running Oracle 11.2).  It works on my local 11.2 database with your sample data.  Using analytic functions to only hit the table once like I'm doing here should be substantially more efficient than hitting the table twice by doing a join so it may be worth understanding what didn't work for you.